# Android emulator not specified

Tags: android, powershell, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When trying to run an AVD from the emulator, using PowerShell:

```
PS C:\android\sdk\emulator> emulator @Pixel_2_64
```

I get the following error, even though the emulator exists:

```
emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'
```

Any ideas? Works fine in CMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for launching an AVD called "Pixel_2_64" in this case, in PowerShell:

Use either:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_64
```

or:

```
emulator "@Pixel_2_64"
```

Have to use the quotation marks or use the **avd** flag.

Thanks to @mklement0 for providing the explanation of...

> `@` is used for [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) in PowerShell, hence the need for quoting; alternatively, you could have `` ` ``-escaped the @ (`` emulator `@Pixel_2_64 ``)